# Referring to a jar inside a library folder of another jar in gradle - class not found

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a grade project that builds base.jar file. This project has a dependency on a 3rd party jar file defined in the gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.abc.something:something')
}
```

when the build task creates the jar file it puts the "something.jar" in the lib folder inside the base.jar file. I think this is okay for me.

Now I have another gradle project called "abc" which has a dependency to the base jar I just created like this

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.myworld:base:1.0.0')
}
```

I would assume that the abc project will have access to the something.jar file inside the lib folder of the base.jar. But for some reason it did not. I keep getting No class def found error when I try to access the classes inside something.jar. Am I missing something?

All I am trying to do is to make sure I have one base.jar built with all the common dependency jar which can be used by different other services just by setting the dependency only to base.jar and not to 50 other jars.

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are resolving the dependency on base.jar.  The way you have the dependency coded will result in gradle trying to pull in the base jar from your respository - maybe a local Maven repo(?), which may not contain the version of base.jar with the external dependencies.  If you have the base jar within the same workspace and parent project you should be able to replace

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.myworld:base:1.0.0')
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':base')
}
```

and hopefully this will fix your problem.